# Getting issue about publishing app to google play store

Tags: android, google-play

I want to publish my app to google play store. But it shows "APP REJECTED".

[image]

[image]

After choosing some different image to screenshots for that problem, and press the "resubmit app" it begins "updates pending", but if I refresh the page, the line "updates pending" disappear, only show the line "Resubmit app".

So I wonder if I must continue to wait or I must change the image again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change package name every time of rejection and screen shots of uploading app this may help you to upload app. b'z package name of rejected app is store in their data base, and make sure you have removed data that violate google policy. be careful about upload app b'z 2-3 times rejection of your app may lead to suspend you play store account permanently.